# Finding .my.cnf with an online host

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new with MySQL, and I am currently using a free online host (0usa, if that matters at all) to do some examples and test with MySQL and PHP. I was reading up on how to login to a database without providing the username and password, and found that it was located in my /etc/mysql/.my.cnf file. I searched my FTP server to look for anything like this, but it wasn't there. Is there a way I can edit this file with an online host? If so how?

Here are my available SSH commands (limited for "security reasons"):
[image: available SSH commands]

Comment: Most likely you are not able to edit `/etc/my.cnf` or even `~/my.cnf` on a shared hosting service.

Comment: @GhostGambler I was kinda figuring that was going to be the case. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @GhostGambler , would it be possible for me to edit the files on a dedicated hosting server?

Comment: This depends on the specific environment and cannot be said so easily. Besides editing the my.cnf for PHP scripts is useless as the MySQL client embedded in PHP will not read that configuration file. It is mostly read by the MySQL clients which are executed from the command line (mysql, mysqlexport, mysqlimport, …)